# How do I center text in a cell with `tcbox`?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have this code in preambule:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{article}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{cmd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{arcs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[scale=0]{background}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage{CJKspace}
\usepackage{CJKpunct}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgheros,tgtermes,tgcursor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{wboiboites}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[total={18.59cm,24.5cm},top=3cm,inner=1cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=red, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[breakable, theorems, skins]{tcolorbox,empheq}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings,theorems}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\tcbset{enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=hkvcyan,colframe=orange,colbacktitle=hkvred!10,
coltitle=black,center title
}
```

And this code in document:

```
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}>{\hsize=.25\hsize}X}
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=90mm,boxsep=1pt,,tabularx={c|c},title= {\textcolor{black}{ Expresiones trigonom\'etricas}}, beamer]

\centering

\textcolor{blue}{Expresi\'on}   & \textcolor{blue}{Grado}   \\ \hline\hline
$5m^{3}n^{4}$&$7$\\

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
```

I need the text inside every cell to be centered horizontally, but my  result is this.
[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, let me check. No, it doesn't

Comment: The text in each cell *is* centred. The width of the right column is not the apparent width - it is the width required to accommodate the longest entry which is `Grado`. The remaining space is beyond the table. You need to define the width to fill the space if that is what you want. You can maybe use `X` with a `tabularx` or use a `p{}` and specify the desired width.

Comment: Please do as @ChristianHupfer requested and post an MWE. That means completing your code to make it compilable, so people can reproduce the output.

Comment: @cfr, exactly in which part? Here `tabularx={c|c}` or where else?

Comment: Please read the link and include only the minimum code necessary to reproduce the issue in your MWE. You certainly cannot require all those packages for this! Yes. That is where you need to specify the width. `c` says to centre the text but it does not specify the width so TeX calculates it based on the contents. Also, your MWE should be a single piece of code people can copy, paste and compile to reproduce. Do not split it up. You certainly need `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` somewhere.

Comment: Off-topic: Your preamble needs editing in any case. There is no point at all in loading all of those font packages as several are simply overriding others. Also, `times` is deprecated and ought not be used. (So it is a shame that this is the one which is *not* being overridden.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution, which simply consists re-defining the `X` column type. I didn't use  your colours (`hkvcyan`, `hkvred`)  as I don't know what they are, and I had to prune your code, as a lot  has nothing to see with your problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage[breakable, theorems, skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=cyan,colframe=orange,colbacktitle=red!10,
coltitle=black,center title
}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}>{\hsize=.25\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=90mm,boxsep=1pt,,tabularx={s|x},title= {\textcolor{black}{ Expresiones trigonométricas}},beamer]
\textcolor{blue}{Expresión} & \textcolor{blue}{Grado} \\ \hline\hline
$5m^{3}n^{4}$&$7$
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]