# Follow-up: Google forms with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

This is a follow-up question from
[Google forms with tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544958/google-forms-with-tcolorbox)

I am trying to get a higher top bar and a title and I get this:
[image]

Is there a way to vertically center the title? When augmenting the height of the title bar, there appears more space above the content text (Some content...). Is it possible to fix that too?

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{googleform-header}{HTML}{673AB7}
\definecolor{googleform-bg}{HTML}{EDE7f6}
\definecolor{googleform-frame}{RGB}{218,219,223}
\definecolor{googleform-pagebg}{RGB}{238,234,247}
\pgfkeys{/tcb/googlebox/.cd,top bar/.initial=1ex,frame arc/.initial=1mm}
\newtcolorbox{googlebox}[1][]{%
  colback=white,colbacktitle=googleform-header,colframe=googleform-frame,
  enhanced,width=0.9\linewidth,%halign title=flush center,
  #1,
  overlay={\pgfmathsetmacro\mytop{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/googlebox/top bar}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myarc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/googlebox/frame arc}}
  \ifdim\mytop pt>\myarc pt
  \fill[googleform-header] 
    ([yshift=-\mytop pt]frame.north west) -- 
    ([yshift=-\myarc pt]frame.north west) arc[start angle=180,end angle=90,radius=\myarc pt]
    --
    ([xshift=-\myarc pt]frame.north east) arc[start angle=90,end angle=0,radius=\myarc pt]
    --
    ([yshift=-\mytop pt]frame.north east)  -- cycle;
 \fi},
  boxrule=0.6pt,top=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/googlebox/top bar}+2mm,
  arc=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/googlebox/frame arc},
  fontupper=\sffamily,fonttitle=\sffamily
 }

\begin{document}
\fcolorbox{googleform-pagebg}{googleform-pagebg}{\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\centering

\begin{googlebox}[googlebox/top bar=7ex,
title={How to vertically center this title?}]
Some content with too much space above.
\end{googlebox}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `halign title=flush center,` has been commented out -- remove the % sign and try

Comment: As the "h" indicates, it aligns horizontally not vertically. And `valign title=flush center` gives an error: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/valign title' `

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196445/197451-- -- try  `,center title`

Comment: It aligns horizontally...

Comment: `valign=center,`  -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394383/197451

Comment: I tried that but there is no visible difference using `valign=center`

Comment: `title={\vphantom{\scriptsize1}\\How to vertically center this title?}]`

Comment: Thank you @jsbibra, although not the perfect solution, it is a "workaround" for the title.

Comment: I have added as an answer so that you can upvote and/or accept the answer

Comment: @schrödingers-cat maybe you can help?

Comment: You can play with `toptitle` and `bottomtitle` options to move the title up or down inside the title vertical space. Try with something like `toptitle=2ex`, see what happens and adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

A `boxed title` with equal `top` and `bottom` parameters will vertically center the title. Also this box allow to easily draw the title frame with a different color from box frame avoinding to use `overlay'.

As I didn't understand original `arc` and `space` definitions, I've preferred to declare a `newgooglebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{googleform-header}{HTML}{673AB7}
\definecolor{googleform-bg}{HTML}{EDE7f6}
\definecolor{googleform-frame}{RGB}{218,219,223}
\definecolor{googleform-pagebg}{RGB}{238,234,247}

\newtcolorbox{newgooglebox}[2][]{%
    enhanced, boxrule=.6pt, fontupper=\sffamily, fonttitle=\sffamily,
    colframe=googleform-frame, colback=white,
    colbacktitle=googleform-header, arc=1mm, 
    attach boxed title to top,
    boxed title style={colframe=googleform-header, top=3mm, bottom=3mm},
    center,
    title={#2},
    #1
}

\newtcolorbox{backbox}[1][]{%
    enhanced, size=tight, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden, colback=googleform-pagebg, 
    sharp corners, left=8mm, right=8mm, top=2mm, bottom=2mm, halign=center,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{backbox}
\begin{newgooglebox}{How to vertically center this title?} 
Some content with too much space above.
\end{newgooglebox}
\end{backbox}

\begin{backbox}
\begin{newgooglebox}[width=.7\linewidth]{How to vertically center this title?} 
Some content with too much space above.
\end{newgooglebox}
\end{backbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
title={\vphantom{\scriptsize1}\\How to vertically center this title?}]
```

Comment: this is a "workaround" option just for the title and the specified height, that will not work for a different height. Any clues to reduce the space above the content text?